# Multiple Lagrange Interpolation

Tags: functions, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I have a data table looking similar to the one below.

There I have for given x- and y-values respective z-values ($z(x,y)$).

- How can I interpolate the matrix that I find a function that describes $f(x)=z=f(x,y)$?
- Do I need a Multiple Lagrange Interpolation (as described in [this document](http://evoq-eval.siam.org/Portals/0/Publications/SIURO/Vol1_Issue1/A_Simple_Expression_for_Multivariate.pdf?ver=2018-03-30-130233-050)) for this non-linear function?
- What kind of (free) software can I use to achieve this?

| y | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 | x7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y1 | z (x1,y1) | z (x2,y1) | z (x3,y1) | z (x4,y1) | z (x5,y1) | z (x6,y1) | z (x7,y1) |
| y2 | z (x1,y2) | z (x2,y2) | z (x3,y2) | z (x4,y2) | z (x5,y2) | z (x6,y2) | z (x7,y2) |
| y3 | z (x1,y3) | z (x2,y3) | z (x3,y3) | z (x4,y3) | z (x5,y3) | z (x6,y3) | z (x7,y3) |
| y4 | z (x1,y4) | z (x2,y4) | z (x3,y4) | z (x4,y4) | z (x5,y4) | z (x6,y4) | z (x7,y4) |
| y5 | z (x1,y5) | z (x2,y5) | z (x3,y5) | z (x4,y5) | z (x5,y5) | z (x6,y5) | z (x7,y5) |
| y6 | z (x1,y6) | z (x2,y6) | z (x3,y6) | z (x4,y6) | z (x5,y6) | z (x6,y6) | z (x7,y6) |
| y7 | z (x1,y7) | z (x2,y7) | z (x3,y7) | z (x4,y7) | z (x5,y7) | z (x6,y7) | z (x7,y7) |
| y8 | z (x1,y8) | z (x2,y8) | z (x3,y8) | z (x4,y8) | z (x5,y8) | z (x6,y8) | z (x7,y8) |
| y9 | z (x1,y9) | z (x2,y9) | z (x3,y9) | z (x4,y9) | z (x5,y9) | z (x6,y9) | z (x7,y9) |

**Given Numbers:**

| f(x,y)=z | 0 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 | 45 | 50 | 55 | 60 | 65 | 70 | 75 | 80 | 85 | 90 | 95 | 100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 4 | -16 | -32 | -48 | -63 | -76 | -90 | -103 | -116 | -124 | -128 | -132 | -136 | -139 | -136 | -128 | -118 | -100 | -75 | -40 | 2 |
| 50 | 16 | 0 | -18 | -32 | -48 | -63 | -78 | -90 | -100 | -111 | -118 | -123 | -125 | -128 | -125 | -121 | -112 | -96 | -70 | -37 | 4 |
| 75 | 44 | 26 | 8 | -10 | -27 | -44 | -57 | -70 | -84 | -96 | -104 | -110 | -116 | -118 | -116 | -113 | -100 | -83 | -60 | -30 | 12 |
| 100 | 66 | 51 | 32 | 13 | -7 | -22 | -38 | -53 | -68 | -79 | -88 | -95 | -100 | -106 | -103 | -98 | -90 | -72 | -48 | -16 | 21 |
| 125 | 96 | 76 | 57 | 36 | 18 | -2 | -20 | -36 | -49 | -60 | -72 | -80 | -86 | -92 | -90 | -86 | -75 | -60 | -38 | -11 | 27 |
| 150 | 120 | 96 | 77 | 56 | 36 | 17 | -4 | -18 | -33 | -44 | -55 | -64 | -70 | -74 | -74 | -71 | -63 | -46 | -26 | 5 | 39 |
| 175 | 144 | 124 | 102 | 79 | 57 | 36 | 19 | 1 | -17 | -28 | -40 | -50 | -56 | -63 | -64 | -60 | -50 | -33 | -18 | 16 | 44 |
| 200 | 164 | 146 | 123 | 100 | 80 | 60 | 40 | 23 | 5 | -9 | -21 | -32 | -41 | -48 | -50 | -47 | -40 | -28 | -7 | 20 | 58 |
| 225 | 180 | 160 | 138 | 116 | 95 | 77 | 58 | 38 | 20 | 5 | -10 | -20 | -28 | -35 | -38 | -36 | -29 | -16 | 6 | 30 | 64 |
| 250 | 180 | 160 | 138 | 116 | 95 | 77 | 58 | 41 | 29 | 18 | 4 | -10 | -17 | -24 | -28 | -24 | -16 | -5 | 18 | 44 | 73 |
| 300 | 180 | 160 | 138 | 116 | 95 | 77 | 58 | 41 | 29 | 18 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 2 | 9 | 20 | 36 | 60 | 92 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I hope my edit clarifies my question

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. You say that you want an interpolating function, so there may be better ways of doing this depending on your application, but I'll show how to construct a polynomial going through all the points.

In one variable if you want to construct a polynomial $P$ through three points  $P(x_1)=y_1$, $P(x_2)=y_2$, $P(x_3)=y_3$ you know you need $P$ to have degree 2 in general. So $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. You can then just substitute and find

$$ax_1^2+bx_1+c=y_1$$

$$ax_2^2+bx_2+c=y_2$$

$$ax_3^2+bx_3+c=y_3$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
x_3^2 & x_3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So then you just solve the linear system in $a,b,c$ and you're done. In more variables you can do the same thing. Say, if you want a polynomial through four points $P(x_1,y_1)=z_1$, $P(x_1,y_2)=z_2$, $P(x_2,y_1)=z_3$, $P(x_2,y_2)=z_4$ you can try a polynomial of degree 1 in $x$ and $y$ but then $P(x)=a+bx+cy$ you have a system of 4 equations in 3 unknowns so it doesn't have a solution in general. Then you can add more terms as you see fit, for example you can add a $x^2$ term.

In the example in the question you can do

$$P(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^{11}\sum_{k=0,k+j\leq 11}^{11} a_{jk}x^jy^k$$

So you have a system of 63 equations in 66 unknowns and you can solve that with something like numpy.

Comment: Thank for your elaborate answer.
What would be the steps for a python code?

Comment: And why do the sums go from 0 to 11?
Why 63 equ. and 66 unknows?

Comment: @Capt.Krusty because you wrote 63 equations in your questions and I chose the degree of the polynomial so that the system would have more than 63 unknowns so it would be guaranteed to have a solution. The relevant documentation for python is here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

Comment: I have updated my questions with real numbers. If you plot them you will see that most of the curves can be interpolated with a quadtratic/cubic polynom.
As far as I understood, `numpy.linalg` won't work as I need quadratic/cubic terms in my array to solve them. What are my next steps? Can I use `numpy.polyfit`?
If yes, how would I start?